# ¿Por que mi instancia se eleva a más del 100%?

Tags: aws, ec2

Recientemente actualice a una instancia EC2 pero sigo teniendo en mi métrica valores altos en donde me veo obligado a reiniciarla para poder hacer que trabaje nuevamente.

Comment: mira que es dificil que una instancia trabaje por encima del 100%... en cualquier caso si tiene valores altos es porque hay al menos un proceso activo haciendo "_algo_"

Comment: gracias @eferion el detalle está en que la instancia anterior que cambie tenia valores arriba de 100% y esto ya lo hacia a diario, después de aumentar a una instancia que determine yo, fue más estable pero el gusto me duró poco ya que volvió a hacerlo aunque paulatinamente para ser sincero.